# how is JanusGraph doing with Spark, are there any latest examples experience with it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, janusgraph

has anyone experienced with spark streaming writing and reading to JanusGraph? I am trying following code from tinkerpop tests

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-gremlin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

 def getSparkJanusConfig: BaseConfiguration = {
    val conf = new BaseConfiguration()
    conf.setProperty(Graph.GRAPH, "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph")
    conf.setProperty("gremlin.hadoop.graphInputFormat", "org.janusgraph.hadoop.formats.cassandra.CassandraInputFormat")
    //    ####################################
    //    # Cassandra Cluster Config         #
    //    ####################################
    conf.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.backend", "cassandrathrift")
    conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "cassandra")
    conf.setProperty("storage.hostname", "127.0.0.1")
    conf.setProperty("cassandra.input.partitioner.class", "org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner")
    //    ####################################
    //    # Spark Configuration              #
    //    ####################################
    conf.setProperty("spark.master", "local[4]")
    conf.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_SPARK_PERSIST_CONTEXT, "true")
    conf.setProperty(Constants.SPARK_SERIALIZER, "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.gryo.GryoSerializer")

    conf
  }

  /* SAVING TO JANUS */
  val gremlinSpark = Spark.create(spark.sparkContext)
  val graph = GraphFactory.open(getSparkJanusConfig)
```